# How to fix MultiBinding cannot be set because the MultiValueConverter must be specified

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I'm new to the WPF app. I used Material Design for the first time. I wanted to round off the button by changing the template and setting the corner radius, but it threw this exception:

> MultiBinding cannot be set because the MultiValueConverter must be
> specified.

***1.Does the library even allow this or did I install the library wrong?***

***2.Does exist some great library like in WinForms(Bunifu,Guna)***

Here is my simple XAML code:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Programming_Manager"
         xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" x:Class="Programming_Manager.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="{materialDesign:PackIcon Kind=HamburgerMenu, Size=50}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" Height="95" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MaterialDesignFloatingActionMiniSecondaryLightButton}"/>
        <Button   Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="467,316,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="184" Height="64"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
<Application x:Class="Programming_Manager.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Programming_Manager"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style x:Key="RoundButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="DodgerBlue" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border CornerRadius="20" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="1">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: This is not a good question. By reviewing the button element alone nobody can tell you about the cause of the the error nor can anybody reproduce it. If your posted code is the only code you wrote to trigger the error, you must show how you configured the Material Design library. The error is obvious from inside the library, probably because you forgot to include required resources. Visit the Material Design homepage to find good examples to learn which resources you need to import (e.g., into your App.xaml resources).

Comment: @BionicCode Hi I've edited it

Comment: I'm not convinced that the source of error is the Button. When you copy your code into a blank solution and run it, do you still get  t  he error?

Comment: At which line you are getting error?

Comment: @saivineeth right on the first line

Comment: @BionicCode Yes,in a blank solution without library it works

Comment: No, blank solution with library of course. The posted code.

Comment: @BionicCode I tried to create my own teplamte for button, but I don't know how to implement it in the buttons in the library

Comment: You import the library resources and apply the styles. My question was if the posted code works in a blank solution. If it does then the error is not related to your button/library resources and not related to the posted code.

Comment: @No it doesn't work

Comment: @BionicCode But I thouthg I should change it directly in the code

Comment: Sure, if you only need a round button then you don't need any library to achieve this. How do you get Material Design, via NuGet?

Comment: Hard to believe that you have tested it in a blank solution. I can bet that your code does not generate this error.

Comment: @BionicCode Yeah,via Nuget and then I just follow the instructions in GitHub

Comment: @BionicCode rounded Material design button is my goal

Comment: @BionicCode I am new in WPF app,so I don't know how to change shape of Material Design Themes button

Comment: I just took a minute to install Material Design via NuGet and to paste in your code. It works as expected.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: And the button's corners are rounded?

Comment: You just installed Material Desing Nuget?Nothing more?

Comment: Yes, nothing more

Comment: @BionicCode Can you poste it as answer please?

Comment: Post what? I used your exact code - copy&paste. Does it work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a custom template at all. MaterialDesign has a built-in attached property to customize the corner radius of a button: `ButtonAssist.CornerRadius`.

```
<Button Content="Do it" materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="20"/>
```